# python loop over unequal list row

Tags: python

I have two tex files which contain unequal number of rows and columns. Now I want to compare list from one tex file with other file, and if it is match with list in other file, then print corresponding number. For e.g. my files look like

```
test1.txt       test2.txt

XCJ2200, B      XCJ1945, A, 0.1
XCJ2345, E      XCJ2200, B, 0.2
XCJ2568, F      XCJ2450, C, 0.3
....            XCJ2590, D, 0.4
                XCJ3000, E, 0.4
                ....
```

So now I want to match col 1 and 2 of test1.txt with col 1 and 2 of test2.txt. So I want final output

```
XCJ2200  0.2
XCJ2345  0.4
XCJ2568
....
```

So far I have written following code but it is not giving answer as I want:

```
reader1=csv.reader(open('test1.txt','rb'))
reader2=csv.reader(open('test2.txt','rb'))
col1=[];col2=[];Col1=[];Col2=[];Col3=[]
for row in reader1:
   col1.append((row[0]))
   col2.append((row[1]))
for row in reader2:
   Col1.append((row[0]))
   Col2.append((row[1]))
   Col3.append((row[2]))
for i in range(len(col1)):
   for j in range(len(Col1)):
     if Col1[j]==col1[i] or Col2[j]==col1[i]:
         print col1[i],Col3[j]
     else:
         print col1[i]
```

This code is printing col 1 of test1.txt in multiple times of length of col 1 of test2.txt. I know that there is something wrong in last if and else condition.

Comment: can you attach what the code is printing out right now? or a sample of it?
Also, I don't see how `Col2[j]==col1[i]` would ever return true. I think you mean `Col2[j]==col2[i]`

Comment: Yes you are right. It is Col2[j]==col2[i]. This code was giving me XCJ2200
XCJ2200  0.2
XCJ2200
XCJ2200
XCJ2345
XCJ2345
XCJ2345  0.3
XCJ2345

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the easiest things to do is to read the test2.txt into a dictionary that you can use to lookup the tuple(row[0], row[1]). Using dict.get() allows you to specify a default "":

```
with open('test2.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lookup = {(row[0], row[1]): row[2] for row in reader}
with open('test1.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in reader]
for d in data:
    print d[0], lookup.get(d, "")
```

Comment: Yes this is I wanted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mentioned that this code is not checking my other condition, ie  `Col2[j]==col2[i]'.

Comment: It should because it is checking the tuples `(row[0], row[1])` are equal, which in your code was Col1 and Col2.

Comment: So what should be the solution? Is there any other option which should I look?

Comment: This should be checking both Col1 and Col2. Suggest you post another question showing your code and the results and your expected results.